# Hugging Face transformer - object not callable

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to make a text summarizer using the T5 transformer from Hugging Face.

From the Hugging Face site I am running this:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5Model

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5Model.from_pretrained("t5-small")
```

Before this I pip installed transformers, sentencepiece, and datasets transformers[sentencepiece]

When I run it I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 2
      1 # Load the T5 model and tokenizer
----> 2 tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
      3 model = T5Model.from_pretrained("t5-small")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I restarted the kernel and then it worked